# quiero inyectar unas imagenes desde mi array

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer que se inyecten las imagenes en el html y queden ahi guardadas, pero, no se guardan, solo corre con una sola imagen y las demas no aparecen, es como si el `for` no funcionara.

```
const displayedImage = document.querySelector('.displayed-img');

const thumbBar = document.querySelector('.thumb-bar');

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

const array = ["images/pic5.jpg","images/pic4.jpg", "images/pic3.jpg","images/pic2.jpg", "images/pic1.jpg",]

let text = ["alto", "bajo", "petiso", "gordo", "delgado"]

var newImage = document.createElement('img');

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
    newImage.setAttribute('src', `${array[i]}`);
    newImage.setAttribute('alt', `${text[i]}`);
    thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);
}
```

Comment: La sentencia `var newImg = document.createElement('img')` debería estar dentro del `for` también, ya que debes crear un nodo por cada imagen que deseas introducir en tu contenedor.